# How can I use DataBinding (with SQL database in Visual Studio) on a ComboBox that will only display the drop-down information once (no duplicates)?

Tags: c#, data-binding, visual-studio-2013, combobox, ssms

I set the DataSource to the table. I set the DisplayMember to Area_Name and the ValueMember to Area_ID. The ComboBox shows all the values for Area_Name including duplicates. I want the ComboBox to just show a list containing 4 values: N/A, Unknown, Test, 4CL. The ComboBox has to account for different Areas being added and deleted from SQL. I thought binding the Area_ID to ValueMember would solve this. Any help is appreciated.

An example dataset in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Area_ID  |  Area_Name  
---------------------
-2       |  N/A  
-1       |  Unknown  
2069     |  Test  
2069     |  Test  
2066     |  4CL  
2066     |  4CL
2066     |  4CL
```

Comment: so what's your query look like.. are you familiar with the reserved word `DISTINCT || GROUP BY`

Comment: @MethodMan, I used DISTINCT in my query and fixed my issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "GROUP BY Area_ID, Area_Name" to the end of your SQL if you haven't already. Otherwise it's due to other fields in your SQL that cannot be grouped together that you might want to exclude in the fill for this ComboBox.
Thanks